# iOS ETManager handleNotification method cannot present cloud page

Tags: ios, mobilepush-ios

I'm running the JBSDK4 in an iOS app, but when I try to open a Cloud Page message the app opens but the landing page is not displayed, looking the debug messages I realised that the ETWKLandingPagePresenter could not be presented because the NavigationController that the PushManager is trying to use has no view in the window hierarchy. Here is some of my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("DID RECEIVE REMOTE NOTIFICATION userInfo: \(userInfo)")

    ETPush.pushManager().handleNotification(userInfo, forApplicationState: application.applicationState)

    if let notificationInfo = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
        if notificationInfo["content-available"] != nil {
            print("DID HANDLE SILENT NOTIFICATION")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
        } else {
            print("DID RESET BADGE COUNT")
            ETPush.pushManager().resetBadgeCount()
        }

    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
}
```

I checket the payload of the push and everything is fine:

```
Received remote notification: {
"_m" = XXX;
"_x" = "https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/XXX/";
aps =     {
    alert = "iOS CloudPage 7";
    badge = 9;
    sound = default;
};
}
```

The problem error in the debug log is the following:

```
2016-04-25 18:59:02.955 XXX[299:32505] Warning: Attempt to present <ETInternalLandingPagePresenter: 0x15e5f6cd0> on
<XXX.CleanNavigationController: 0x15f00c200> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

As seen I'm running swift using the bridge support and iOS 9.3. The SDK state is fine and cloud page support is set in the SDK configuration. I can give any additional information needed to understand the problem.

**UPDATE:**

I made a workaround based in what I saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29910341/1080583). Assuming that the landing page presentation was made using the wrong navigation controller, I simply made a presentation myself using the method described in the post above.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("DID RECEIVE REMOTE NOTIFICATION userInfo: \(userInfo)")

    ETPush.pushManager().handleNotification(userInfo, forApplicationState: application.applicationState)

    if let notificationInfo = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
        if notificationInfo["content-available"] != nil {
            print("DID HANDLE SILENT NOTIFICATION")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
        } else {
            print("DID RESET BADGE COUNT")
            ETPush.pushManager().resetBadgeCount()
        }

    }

    if let landingURL = userInfo["_x"] {
        let landingViewController = ETWKLandingPagePresenter(forLandingPageAt: landingURL as! String)

        let currentController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        currentController.visibleViewController?.navigationController?.presentViewController(landingViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)

}
```

The problem is, as the handleNotification method already tries to make the presentation it is now doubled, I wonder if this problem only happens in swift or in ios 9+, if so I could have some weird behaviour in diferent environments.

I still need some enlightenment.

Comment: `ETPush` exposes that API to centralize routing of notifications and allow them to perform their own custom handling. This rather sounds like a bug in ETPush that they should resolve, and until then, you are short-circuiting, or doubling that logic by providing your own notification handling. That will cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I think that is happening. When I stop the notification handling using breakpoints sometimes the default landing page is presented, but the normal behaviour is bugged.